# Differential equation $y=xy' + \frac{1}{2}(y')^2$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

In one of my exams, there has been an equation that looks like this
$$y=xy' + \frac{1}{2}(y')^2$$

I have tried to solve it, but couldn't figure out how, since we haven't really learned that particular method.

So, I would really appreciate if someone could give me an idea or an explanation on how to approach this problem. Thanks

Comment: Use the quadratic formula to solve for y'.

Comment: @user247327 Do you mean that I should substitute y' with for example t, (y')^2 with t^2 and y with 1?

Comment: @ivana14 why would $y$ become $1$?

Comment: It's something we usually did when solving some equations. y' gets substituted by t, and y gets substituted by 1. I have never really been sure why, though

Comment: @ivana14 I think I see what you mean. I think you're thinking of when you have an equation such as $y''-2y'-2y=0$, and you 'guess' a solution of the form $y=e^{mx}$ which, after you substitute it and divide everything by $e^{mx}$, is equivalent to substituting $m^2$ for $y''$, $m$ for $y'$ and $1$ for $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply by 2 your differential equation:

$$\tag{1}2y=2xy' + (y')^2 \ \iff \ 2y=(y'+x)^2-x^2 \ \iff \ 2y+x^2=(y'+x)^2$$

Setting $$\tag{2}u:=2y+x^2,$$

the last expression in (1) becomes:

$$u=(\tfrac12u')^2 \ \iff \ u'=2\sqrt{u} \ \iff \ \dfrac{u'}{2\sqrt{u}}=1$$

equivalent, by integration, to: $\sqrt{u}=x+C$ ($C$ being an arbitrary constant), that is to say:

$$\tag{3}u=(x+C)^2.$$

It suffices now to plug (3) into (2) in order to get the general solution:

> $$\tag{4}y=Cx+\tfrac12C^2.$$

---

Edit: I am indebted to @projectilemotion (see his solution) who has remarked that there is an exceptional solution with equation

> $$\tag{5}y=-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2.$$

that can guessed as all straight lines described by (4) have an envelope, i.e., a parabola described by equation (5).

See figure below where this envelope curve is in red.

[image]

Comment: I think you've missed out one solution: $$y(x)=-\frac{x^2}{2}$$ Please see my answer.

Comment: @projectilemotion You are right. It is the exceptional solution which is the **envelope** of the ordinary solutions I have found.

Answer (score 1):

Your ODE is given by:
$$y(x)=x\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 \tag{1}$$
This is a [Clairaut Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation) because it is in the form:

> $$y(x)=x\frac{dy}{dx}+f\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$

---

To solve this type, differentiate both sides wrt. $x$ to obtain:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=x\cdot \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$$
Factoring gives:
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}+x\right)=0$$
Hence, we must solve for the following separately (They are easy to solve):
$$\begin{cases} \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}=0 \\ \frac{dy}{dx}+x=0 \end{cases}$$

---

For $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}=0$, integrate both sides to obtain:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=C \tag{2}$$
And then substitute this into $(1)$ to obtain $y(x)$.

For $\frac{dy}{dx}+x=0$, just rearrange to obtain:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-x \tag{3}$$
And then substitute this into $(1)$ to obtain $y(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

If we say that $\ y'=t$ then because $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=t$ we have that  $dy=tdx$. After introducing the shift, our equation looks like this $\ y=xt+\dfrac{1}{2}t^2$ After this step we have to solve this $\ dy= \dfrac{∂y}{∂x}dx+\dfrac{∂y}{∂p}dt$ and we get $\ =>tdx=tdx+(x+t)dt⟹(x+t)dt=0$ 
Then we integrate and represent our solution in terms of y.

Comment: It is not very easy to follow what you mean...

Comment: I'll try my best to explain in the next edit.

Answer (score 0):

$\ (y')^2=t =>y'=\sqrt{t}$

$\ y'=\dfrac{dy}{dx} => \dfrac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{t}=>dy=\sqrt{t}dx$

$\ y=\int{\sqrt{t}dx} => y=\sqrt{t}x+C,\ C\in{R}\tag{1}$

All off this we put in the equation and get the following

$\ \sqrt{t}x+C=\sqrt{t}x+\dfrac{t}{2} => t=2C=> \sqrt{t}=\sqrt{2C}\tag{2}$

Inserting (2) in (1) we get $\ y=\sqrt{2C}x+C$

Comment: I think you've missed out one solution: $$y(x)=-\frac{x^2}{2}$$ Please see my answer.

Comment: @projectilemotion yes, yes. you have a point. I've overseen the exceptonal solution.